# Product discount laravel, get actual price

Tags: php, laravel

I have model Product, in table products I have column `discount` and column `price`. How I can update price with discount in model? And get actual price and old price? I have function:

```
class Product extends Model
{

protected $guarded = [];

public function getPriceAttribute() {
    return $this->price * (1 - $this->discount / 100);
} 

}
```

With attribute `price` I get updated price, but How I can get old price of this product?

Comment: You are doing an accessor function (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)
that's why you are seeing the discounted price with you get the price attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use another attribute for discounted price to get old price.

```
class Product extends Model
{

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function getDicountedPriceAttribute()
    {
        return $this->price * (1 - $this->discount / 100);
    }
}

$product->price //old price
$product->discounted_price //price with discount
```